# Can't include vue related npm package to my Laravel + Vue project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I want to include beatiful flash messages to mey Laravel + Vue app, so I found a npm package on GitHub and installed this in my app (npm install)

I'm beginner in VueJs and I'm facing a problem: I just can't use the package in my vue components since it throw errors when I try to include this

**What I use and what I get:**

it's my app.js code

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

/*including the package*/
import FlashMessage from '@smartweb/vue-flash-message';
Vue.use(FlashMessage);
/*including the package*/

Vue.component('settings-form',require('./components/SettingsFormComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('profile-nav',require('./components/ProfileNavComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

What error I get using the code:

*"TypeError: Cannot read property 'flashMessage' of undefined at app.js:1863"*

[image]

I run this method (**flashMessage**) when I want to output a message: 
[image]

**Also I tried to use this code in my app.js to include the packange:**

```
Vue.component('FlashMessage', require('@smartweb/vue-flash-message').default);
```

but it doesn't work too, it throws this error: 
*"Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined ..."* 
[image]

I'm trying to use my component that way (in ProfileNavComponent.vue):

```
 <FlashMessage></FlashMessage>
```

Could you please tell me what the problem can be in? 
thanks guys for any help)
I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use vue packages adding them from the name of the package, try:

```
import FlashMessage from 'vue-flash-message';
```

And when you want to use the component, try to use `FlashMessage.show()`.

Answer (score 1):

Im an author of this package. If you will have some issues with it, please leave the issue on github: https://github.com/smwbtech/vue-flash-message/issues

About your problem, I suppose that it is function context issue. Try to use arrow function as callback for .then

```js
axios.post('/api/post/', body)
  .then( res => {
    this.flashMessage(/*your message*/);
    this.data = '';/*other actions with your component data*/
  })
  .catch(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I uncluded the package into my project

in app.js I added that code:

```
import FlashMessage from '@smartweb/vue-flash-message';
Vue.use(FlashMessage, {tag: 'flash-message', strategy: 'multiple'});
```

And then in any component I wanted to use flashMessages I used code like this:

```
  this.flashMessage.success({
   title: 'New Friend!',
   message: data.user_created_by.full_name + ' started chatting with you!',
   time: 5000,
   blockClass: 'image-uploaded-flash',
 });
```

Thanks a lot guys all who wanted to help me!!!